# consulta perdida de informacion arraylist java sockets

Tags: java, servidor, socket

Buenos días quería saber si hay algún problema respecto a enviar un arraylist de strings mediante el uso de sockets, es decir, tengo una aplicación de chat donde si envío el arraylist de clientes, que guarda sus nombres, desde el servidor a dos clientes distintos, el primero recibe los dos nombres y el segundo solo recibe un nombre.En cambio, si envío los nombres de los clientes mediante un string primitivo llega la informacion completa a ambos clientes.

Comment: Necesitamos que pongas algo de código, para ver como lo tienes montado, lo que has intentado y lo que no, ya que a primera vista es imposible saber lo que pasa sin información.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer y si se puede hacer. Te dejo el link de uno que preguntó lo mismo, aunque está en inglés. :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895450/sending-an-arrayliststring-from-the-server-side-to-the-client-side-over-tcp-us
Espero que te sirva :)